# Define Many to Many without a foreignKey in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have existing data that I want to model.  Its essentially:

```
class Investor(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(id, primary_key=True)
    investments = db.relationship('Investments', backref='investor')

class Round(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('id', primary_key=True)

investments = db.Table(
    'investments',
    db.Column('investor_id', db.ForeignKey('investor.id')),
    db.Column('round_id', db.ForeignKey('round.id')),
)
```

Now, every time I try execute this little model, I get the following error:
expression 'Investments' failed to locate a name

I understand, that investments, needs to be a class, but I've tried making a dummy class with db.model, and it hasn't really worked.  In that version I get problems with asking for a primary join or a mapper.  I'm quite confused, and a little guidance would help greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the many to many relationship is between `Investor` and `Round`, You can define the model as follows:

```
class Investor(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    rounds = db.relationship('Round', secondary=investments, backref='investor')

class Round(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

investments = db.Table(
    'investments',
    db.Column('investor_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('investor.id')),
    db.Column('round_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('round.id')))
```